# Google Firestore Scalability Limit

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

As per the Google Firebase documentation, Firestore will support upto 1,000,000 simultaneous connections and 10,000 writes per second per database. We have ran a scalalbility test to check the Firestore is viable for our solution and encountering the errors like "Connect to firebase.googleapis.com:443:Connection timed out" during write operations for 40K samples, "firestore.googleapis.com:443:failed to respond" during GET operations while the 40K samples writing. Would like to understand the Firestore limits and its scalalbility

Running JMeter script to write data to Firebase (Firestore Blaze Plan purchased for testing) on multiple VMs and PCs which are connected to wired network to check the scalalbility. The JMeter script write data to Firebase using REST API PATCH and each script on PC/VM writes 5K data in a period 5 minutes. There are total of 8 PC/VM which writes 40K data to Firebase. During this we also GET 500 records in 5 minutes 2 times a day. During this test we are htting the Firebase failures

The errors are "Connect to firebase.googleapis.com:443:Connection timed out" during write operations for 40K samples, "firestore.googleapis.com:443:failed to respond" and Connection reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you considering the other limits for your specific operations?

According to https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas

For example, for the write operation:

- Maximum writes per second per database = 10,000 (up to 10 MiB per second)
- Maximum write rate to a document=  1 per second
- Maximum write rate to a collection in which documents contain sequential values in an indexed field = 500 per second
- Maximum number of writes that can be passed to a Commit operation or performed in a transaction   = 500

During GET operations you have the limits: Maximum number of exists(), get(), and getAfter() calls per request:

10 for single-document requests and query requests.
20 for multi-document reads, transactions, and batched writes. The previous limit of 10 also applies to each operation.

For example, imagine you create a batched write request with 3 write operations and that your security rules use 2 document access calls to validate each write. In this case, each write uses 2 of its 10 access calls and the batched write request uses 6 of its 20 access calls.

Exceeding either limit results in a permission denied error.

Some document access calls may be cached, and cached calls do not count towards the limits.

I think that some parameter could be causing the abortion of these connections.